# How to resize/stretch a text box based on another text box content?

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, resize

I would like to resize my text box based on another text box content.

This is what I've tried to do.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    receive.AutoSize = true;
    receive.Text = send.Text;
}
```

I want the text box to auto stretch or to resize on X and Y based on another text box content.

Comment: I need in windows form.

Comment: based on what though? the size of the other box, what a text box contains, what a line contains, are you looking for a specific character?

Comment: I'm not sure why you're using a button click. If you want to do something as a result of a text box being resized by the users (*e.g.*, resize another text box), then you can respond to a [resize event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.control.resize?view=netframework-4.7.2) for the first text box and resize the second based upon that event.

Comment: Okay, you tell us what you want and what you've already tried. But what exactly doesn't work with your solution? Please consider reading our [ask] topics explaining how to ask a well-received question.

Comment: create on the other textbox an event Resize and put your behavior in his subscriber

Comment: So I type text in Send.Text 
This is like a chat box.
And receive.Text is like a chat bubble.
So when I press send button, the text bubble supposed to resize itself.

Comment: So for me as a new C# user, I would like to see a code example, please.

Comment: How does layout looks like? You could utilize `TableLayoutPanel` and docking to match size of one control to another autosized control. But you say "content", do you mean text length or what?

Comment: Yes, text length and amount of new lines. So I need that box get resize in X and Y as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, So I found something like this.

```
    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        receive.Text = send.Text;
        Size sz = new Size(receive.ClientSize.Width, int.MaxValue);
        TextFormatFlags flags = TextFormatFlags.WordBreak;
        int padding = 3;
        int borders = receive.Height - receive.ClientSize.Height;
        sz = TextRenderer.MeasureText(receive.Text, receive.Font, sz, flags);
        int h = sz.Height + borders + padding;
        if (receive.Top + h > this.ClientSize.Height - 10)
        {
            h = this.ClientSize.Height - 10 - receive.Top;
        }
        receive.Height = h;
    }
```

But I need to set Maximum Height and Width and minimum. How should I do it?

Answer (score 0):

```
 private void sender_TextChanged/*or button1_Click*/(object sender, EventArgs e)
 {
      Graphics graph = CreateGraphics();

      SizeF measuredStringSize = graph.MeasureString(tb_sender.Text, tb_sender.Font);

      tb_receiver.Width = (int)measuredStringSize.Width;
      tb_receiver.Text = tb_sender.Text;
 }
```

Comment: I like your code, but I also need Height. 
When I add this line in your code receive.Height = (int)measuredStringSize.Height;
It does something but doesn't resize it properly.

Comment: It allows me to show 7 lines down maximum. Is there any chance to change it to the limit into character amount instead of line limit?

Comment: Any Idea? why I get only 7 lines shown maximum?
Can it measure also against what min and max measurements I set in form?